# Display image against default screen in android studio application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

em new to android development the problem em facing is that i have an web view application for that i want to display image against the screen which shows internet is not connected. i have applied check for the internet connection. but now i have no idea how to add or what code to add for displaying image in that check. following code I am using for Check.

```
ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nInfo !=null && nInfo.isConnected())
    {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {


       Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network is Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Network is Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this;

this will works fine.

```
 connection = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    if (!isInternetPresent) {
        hidePDialog();
        connection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        note.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
             connection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            note.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

             **Do What U want here**

}
```

ConnectDetector class

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();

        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```